# C - subtracting a string from another

Tags: c, string, subtraction

Using `ftw()` function, I have a list of paths I want to write on a file. 
I need only paths starting from a specified folder, like:

```
source folder: /Users/me
subfolder1:    /Users/me/school
subfolder2:    /Users/me/school/english

result I need: /school  
               /school/english
```

Is there a way to "subtract" one string from another, in the way i explained above? I know there is `strtok()`function, but i don't know if it works with more than one char at a time.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for the term "substring"

Comment: >Is there a way - Yes, there is a way. Please search and write a code. If that has problems, then show us your code.

Comment: I didn't want you to make code for me. Since my C knowledge is very limited, I wanted to know if there (eventually) was a function that works as I needed, and name of it. Nothing more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the prefix is there, just skip it:

```
char *result = subfolder + strlen(source);
```